# How to draw a graph along with probabilty tables using TikZ package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, graphs

I need help to draw a Directed Acyclic Graph of Bayesian Network along with probability of each node using TikZ package. Here is an example:

[image]

Table grid can be a full or partial as in above example.

Comment: You can put an entire `tabular` environment inside a tikz node, so you can integrate your tables in the tikz figure. It is all about node placement. Use `positioning` library.

Comment: This is very similar to [Balanced Scorecard diagram](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34075/5764). If you're not hooked on [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), then the code could be adapted to produce the required output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am in a good mood to provide you with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) but in future questions, I advise you to provide one. (Summer break for teachers here :) See for instance: ["Just do it for me" text building block](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/just-do-it-for-me-text-building-block?lq=1)

Here it is in `tikz`. You can do the rest for practice. See the [pgfmanual](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). You can also type `texdoc pgf` in your terminal or command line.

Here are some explanations.

- Usually, node commands are done as follows: `\node (<node name>) [<options>] {<text>};`
- **Edit:** The `positioning` library enables you to specify how far the location of nodes/coordinates relative to other nodes/coordinates. **Reference: [Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `o' or `of'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94386/package-pgf-math-error-unknown-operator-o-or-of)**
- The `arrows` library allows you to use other types of arrows aside from the  default of `>`.
- The `shapes` library allows usage of shapes like ellipse for nodes.

### The partial code

```
\documentclass[border=5, convert={density=150}]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}
\tikzset{
    events/.style={ellipse, draw, align=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, >=stealth']
\node [events] (cloudy) {Cloudy};
\node [events, below left = of cloudy] (sprinkler) {Sprinkler};
\node [events, below right = of cloudy] (rain) {Rain};
\node [events, below right = of sprinkler] (wetgrass) {WetGrass};

\draw [->] (cloudy) -- (sprinkler);
\draw [->] (cloudy) -- (rain);
\draw [->] (rain) -- (wetgrass);
\draw [->] (sprinkler) -- (wetgrass);

\node [above = of cloudy] {
    \begin{tabular}{CC}
    \mathrm{P(C=F)} & \mathrm{P(C=T)}\\
    \hline
    0.5 & 0.5\\
    \end{tabular}
    };

\node [right = of rain, anchor=west] {
    \begin{tabular}{c|CC}
    C & \mathrm{P(C=F)} & \mathrm{P(C=T)}\\
    \hline
    F & 0.8 & 0.2\\
    T & 0.2 & 0.8\\
    \end{tabular}
    };  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### The output

[image]

Comment: Your example even runs without `positioning`. The syntax for `positioning` is `…=… of …`, see [Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator o or of](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94386). The `… of=…` syntax is actually deprecated, see [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I knew there was something off. That is why I had to drop by here early. Thanks a lot!